# Plot two heatmaps together (Seaborn)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have two dataframes that I feed as input to two heatmap functions in seaborn

```
df1_data = 
{'0': {'TPUs': 0.0, 'GPUs': 0.0, 'None': 0.0, 'Other': 0.0}, '1-99': {'TPUs': 1.0434782608695652, 'GPUs': 9.18840579710145, 'None': 7.797101449275362, 'Other': 0.8840579710144928}, '100-999': {'TPUs': 1.9855072463768115, 'GPUs': 13.27536231884058, 'None': 10.115942028985508, 'Other': 0.855072463768116}, '1000-9,999': {'TPUs': 2.0434782608695654, 'GPUs': 15.173913043478262, 'None': 9.681159420289855, 'Other': 0.782608695652174}, '10,000-99,999': {'TPUs': 1.0579710144927537, 'GPUs': 8.391304347826088, 'None': 6.449275362318841, 'Other': 0.3188405797101449}, '100,000 or more': {'TPUs': 0.8260869565217391, 'GPUs': 5.27536231884058, 'None': 4.478260869565218, 'Other': 0.37681159420289856}}
df2_data = 
Other  0.0  0.884058   0.855072    0.782609       0.318841         0.376812
{'0': {'TPUs': 0.0, 'GPUs': 0.0, 'None': 0.0, 'Other': 0.0}, '1-99': {'TPUs': 0.09596928982725528, 'GPUs': 1.9193857965451055, 'None': 7.1017274472168905, 'Other': 0.09596928982725528}, '100-999': {'TPUs': 1.055662188099808, 'GPUs': 7.9654510556621885, 'None': 9.692898272552783, 'Other': 0.19193857965451055}, '1000-9,999': {'TPUs': 1.2476007677543186, 'GPUs': 12.667946257197697, 'None': 12.380038387715931, 'Other': 0.4798464491362764}, '10,000-99,999': {'TPUs': 1.055662188099808, 'GPUs': 8.925143953934741, 'None': 10.844529750479847, 'Other': 0.28790786948176583}, '100,000 or more': {'TPUs': 1.8234165067178503, 'GPUs': 10.652591170825335, 'None': 10.652591170825335, 'Other': 0.8637236084452975}}
```

```
print(df1)

Q25      0      1-99    100-999  1000-9,999  10,000-99,999  100,000 or more
Q12                                                                        
TPUs   0.0  1.043478   1.985507    2.043478       1.057971         0.826087
GPUs   0.0  9.188406  13.275362   15.173913       8.391304         5.275362
None   0.0  7.797101  10.115942    9.681159       6.449275         4.478261
Other  0.0  0.884058   0.855072    0.782609       0.318841         0.376812

print(df2)
Q25      0      1-99   100-999  1000-9,999  10,000-99,999  100,000 or more
Q12                                                                       
TPUs   0.0  0.095969  1.055662    1.247601       1.055662         1.823417
GPUs   0.0  1.919386  7.965451   12.667946       8.925144        10.652591
None   0.0  7.101727  9.692898   12.380038      10.844530        10.652591
Other  0.0  0.095969  0.191939    0.479846       0.287908         0.863724
```

Using these two dataframes, I am able to generate two different heatmaps, like,
[image]

Is it possible combine these two heatmaps into a single heatmap in a triangular format where the upper triangle represents df1 and the lower triangle represents df2 with the same color scale.

It would be great if the plots were made using seaborn

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine multiple heatmaps in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809274/combine-multiple-heatmaps-in-matplotlib)

Comment: The solution in the link provided utilizes matplotlib's scatter function. I was expecting something that used the seaborn's heatmap itself

Comment: It is also difficult to adapt to if the features are categorical

Comment: [Python package to plot two heatmaps in one (split each square into two triangles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530701/python-package-to-plot-two-heatmaps-in-one-split-each-square-into-two-triangles)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JohanC, the plt.tripcolor in the solution produces an image. So it would be difficult to add annotated values in it

Comment: `plt.tripcolor()` creates a mesh of triangles.  With e.g. `plt.text(x, y, f'{value:.2f}')` you can add text, you only have to be careful to add or subtract some offset to have the text near the center of the triangles. Perhaps you need to use a smaller font for everything to fit.