# 3D histograms and Contour plots Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, contour, histogram2d

I have a problem with contourf function of matplotlib. I have a txt data file from which I am importing my data. I have columns of data (pm1 and pm2) and I am performing a 2D histogram. I want to plot this data as a 3D histogram and as a contour plot to see where is located the maximum values.

This is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
rows = np.arange(200,1300,10)

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d (pm1_n, pm2_n, bins = (rows, rows) )
elements = (len(xedges) - 1) * (len(yedges) - 1)


xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])

xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(elements)
dx = 0.1 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

#####The problem is here#####

#ax.contourf(xpos,ypos,hist)
#ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, zsort='average')

plt.show()
```

I can plot the 3d bar graph but I am not able to plot the contour one, If I place `hist` in the contourf function I get the error:  `Length of x must be number of columns in z` and if I place `dz` I get `Input z must be a 2D array`
I also have tried using xedges and yexges but this doesn't solve the problem.

I think that the problem is related with the shape of the return of the function histogram2D. But I don't know how to solve it.

I would also like to perform a 3D bar plot with a colorcode changing form the minimum to the maximum value. Is there anyway to make this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do since I don't know what your data looks like, but it seems wrong to have your `contourf` plot sharing the same axis as your `bar3d` plot. If you add an axis without the 3D projection to a new figure, you should be able to make a `contourf` plot just fine using `hist`. An example using data from a random, normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_points = 1000
x = np.random.normal(0, 2, n_points)
y = np.random.normal(0, 2, n_points)

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=np.sqrt(n_points))

fig2D = plt.figure()
ax2D = fig2D.add_subplot(111)
ax2D.contourf(hist, interpolation='nearest', 
              extent=(xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]))
plt.show()
```

returns an image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2JZ0.png).

As for your second question, regarding a color-coded 3D bar plot, how about this (using the same data as above but with 1/10 the size):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

n_points = 100
x = np.random.normal(0, 2, n_points)
y = np.random.normal(0, 2, n_points)

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=np.sqrt(n_points))

# Following your data reduction process
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])

length, width = 0.4, 0.4
xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(n_points)
dx = np.ones(n_points) * length
dy = np.ones(n_points) * width
dz = hist.flatten()

# This is where the colorbar customization comes in
dz_normed = dz / dz.max()
normed_cbar = colors.Normalize(dz_normed.min(), dz_normed.max())
# Using jet, but should work with any colorbar
color = cm.jet(normed_cbar(dz_normed))

fig3D = plt.figure()
ax3D = fig3D.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax3D.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=color)
plt.show()
```

I get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Pst.png).

Comment: References to colorbar customization lines: [pylab example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hist_colormapped.html)
and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950375/apply-color-map-to-mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-axes3d-bar3d)